# Send a structure through a socket using tpl for serialization using c

Tags: c, sockets, serialization

After reading a few related questions I've decided to use the [tpl library](http://tpl.sourceforge.net/) to serialize my structures in order to send and receive them through sockets. I'm having trouble understanding how to send and receive the tpl images using sockets. I get a segfault error on the server side when I call the `tpl_dump` function.

I know the sockets are working on both end because I was using the code to previously send strings back and forth. I was also able to use tpl to create and read an tpl image on the client without any issues.

This isn't the structure I eventually want to be sending back and forth, but I hope to figure this sample out so I can do this in the future. I know I'm mishandling something between the incoming buffer and the `tpl_dump`. I'm still learning C (as evidenced by my previous questions) so I apologize if I have glaring errors in my code.

**Edits**
The issues Nikolai pointed out have been corrected in the code below. However the server code logs `error: tpl_load to non-root node` and still segfaults at `tpl_unpack(tn, 0);`

Client Code:

```
tpl_node *tn;

void *addr;
size_t len;

struct ci {
        char c;
        int i;
};
struct ci sample = {'a', 1};
tn = tpl_map("S(ci)", &sample); /* pass structure address */
tpl_pack(tn, 0);
tpl_dump(tn, TPL_MEM, &addr, &len );
tpl_free(tn);

send(sockfd, addr, len, 0);
```

Server Code:

```
if ((nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) <= 0) {

//error handling

} else {
    tpl_node *tn;

    struct ci {
        char c;
        int i;
};

struct ci recieve;

tpl_map("S(ci)", &recieve);
tpl_load(tn, TPL_MEM, &buf, &nbytes );
tpl_unpack(tn, 0);
tpl_free(tn);
```

In case this will come in handy - [tpl user's guide](http://tpl.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are misusing the `tpl_dump`, at least on the client - the second argument is supposed to be `void**`, not `int*`. The macro stores address of the allocated buffer into your `addr` integer, so you are sending address (plus some garbage), not data to the server. The sequence of calls on the server side also look out of order.
Looking closer at your source:

- remove ampersands (&) from `buf` and `len`; the `tpl_load` expects `void*` and `size_t`;

  you need to `free()` the memory when you're done;

  you need to watch out for short socket reads - you might get less (or more) then you sent on a read from TCP socket.

Here's a simple complete example without sockets:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tpl.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    char* buffer;
    size_t i, len;
    tpl_node *tn;
    struct ci { char c; int i; } s = {'a', 1}, s1;

    printf( "input {%c,%d}\n", s.c, s.i );

    tn = tpl_map( "S(ci)", &s );  /* pass structure address */
    tpl_pack( tn, 0 );
    tpl_dump( tn, TPL_MEM, &buffer, &len );
    tpl_free( tn );

    printf( "size = %lu\n", len );

    tn = tpl_map( "S(ci)", &s1 );
    tpl_load( tn, TPL_MEM, buffer, len );
    tpl_unpack( tn, 0 );
    tpl_free( tn );
    free( buffer );

    printf( "output {%c,%d}\n", s1.c, s1.i );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that the calls on the server were out of order. I changed the code on the client side from "int addr" to "void *addr."
 is this correct?

Comment: Yes it still segfaults. The question has been updated with my most recent code and errors.

Comment: This solved the problem with handling the tpl side of things correctly. After I corrected my handling of the buffers and sockets I was able to pass the structure successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking at this thread, Eric de Araujo's post from Jul 16 '09 at 14:49 (his corrected code) does work ONLY IF you correct one error in his Server Code section:

```
tpl_map("S(ci)", &receive);
```

must be changed to:

```
tn = tpl_map("S(ci)", &receive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per request, here is a successful implementation using sockets:

Client Code:

```
tpl_node *tn;

    void *addr;
    size_t len;

    struct ci {
            char c;
            int i;
    };

    struct ci sample = {'a', 1};
    tn = tpl_map("S(ci)", &sample); /* pass structure address */
    tpl_pack(tn, 0);
    tpl_dump(tn, TPL_MEM, &addr, &len );
    tpl_free(tn);

    send(sockfd, addr, len, 0);
```

Server Code:

```
char buf[256]; // buffer for client data
int nbytes;

if ((nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) <= 0) {

//error handling

} else {
    tpl_node *tn;

    struct ci {
        char c;
        int i;
    };

struct ci receive;

tpl_map("S(ci)", &receive);
tpl_load(tn, TPL_MEM, buf, nbytes );
tpl_unpack(tn, 0);
tpl_free(tn);

printf("Struct: {%c,%d}\n", receive.c, receive.i);
```